# Geo coordinates operations

Tags: geolocation, distance, pharo

As Esteban A. Maringolo asked:

Has anybody implemented basic methods/classes to calculate distance
between two points (lat, long) and similar operations?

Comment: Who on earth is Esteban A. Maringolo, and why is it relevant?

Comment: @Juhana person who asked question on the mailing list. I decided to move it to SO as here it's more indexable by search engines and people can add other questions, but I still want to give attribution to original authors

Answer (score 1):

Solution found by Esteban A. Maringolo:

```
distanceFromLat: lat1 long: long1 toLat: lat2 long: long2
"Answer the distance in meters between two coordinates in float number representation."

  | lat1Rad  lon1Rad lat2Rad lon2Rad earthRadius dLat dLon dLatSinSqrd dLonSinSqrd cosLatLat a c distance |
  lat1Rad := lat1 degreesToRadians.
  lon1Rad := long1  degreesToRadians.
  lat2Rad := lat2 degreesToRadians.
  lon2Rad := long2 degreesToRadians.
  earthRadius := 6371.00.
  dLat := lat2Rad - lat1Rad.
  dLon := lon2Rad - lon1Rad.
  dLatSinSqrd := (dLat / 2) sin squared.
  dLonSinSqrd := (dLon / 2) sin squared.
  cosLatLat := lat2Rad cos * lat1Rad cos.
  a := dLatSinSqrd + (cosLatLat * dLonSinSqrd).
  c := 2 * a sqrt arcSin.
  distance := earthRadius * c.
  ^ distance
```

Comment: I am a little confused by the question and the answers, particularly since both answers are implementations of the Haversine function for calculating distances between 2 points in the WGN83 datum. Was the question on 'how to implement Haversine in Pharo'. If so, could we retitle the question.

Answer (score 1):

Simpler solution by Sven Van Caekenberghe:

This is the formula that is being used for years in Pharo, Java[Script], Common Lisp:

```
distanceBetween: firstPosition and: secondPosition
 "T3GeoTools distanceBetween: 5.33732@50.926 and: 5.49705@50.82733"

 | c |
 c := (firstPosition y degreeSin * secondPosition y degreeSin)
      + (firstPosition y degreeCos * secondPosition y degreeCos
         * (secondPosition x degreesToRadians - firstPosition x degreesToRadians) cos).
 c := c >= 0 ifTrue: [ 1 min: c ] ifFalse: [ -1 max: c ].
 ^ c arcCos * 6371000
```

This is between WGS84 coordinates. Use this page as reference: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html